# Can storing a system service statically lead to memory leaks?

Tags: java, android, android-context

We all know that storing a context object (other than the application context) statically is bad practice because it can lead to memory leaks. But can you store a system service derived from the context object? Such as `ConnectivityManager`?

```
// Is this okay?
static ConnectivityMananger connectivityManager;
...
connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Service Objects are connected to the Context you used to retrieve them. Use `getApplicationContext()` if you want one that will stay alive for the duration of your app's life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using the application `Context` for getting such a system service:

```
connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

*Probably* all system services use the application `Context` internally, but this approach is incrementally safer, for the cost of an additional method call.

If the system service is using the application `Context`, you will not leak a `Context` when obtaining a system service. Whether you leak anything else through your use of the system service may vary.

Comment: That's what I intended to do, until I read [this post by Matt Dupree](https://www.philosophicalhacker.com/2015/07/14/why-static-references-to-application-contexts-are-probably-not-the-best-idea/) that sort-of convinced me that saving app contexts is also bad.

Comment: @noamtm: That's not how I interpret that post. That post seems to be referring to saving the `Application` context *itself* in a `static` field, then referring to it from anywhere. That's not great. And, if you are using dependency injection, you can probably rig it up to supply you with system services as well as `Application`, so you can get your system services "on demand" where you need it without having to hold them statically yourself.

Comment: In that case, your answer here does not answer my question that you just closed as duplicate. I was asking specifically about storing system services (such as `ConnectivityManager`) for use later when a `Context` is not available. In that case, the other question should be reopened (and I will appreciate your response).